# php on shared hosting not being execute

Tags: php, .htaccess

Here is my `htaccess`

```
# BEGIN LBCWpFastestCache
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf|x-html|css|xml|js|woff|ttf|svg|eot)(\.gz)?$">
<IfModule mod_expires.so>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/ico A2592000
ExpiresByType text/css A2592000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A2592000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Expires "max-age=2592000, public"
Header unset ETag
</IfModule>
FileETag None
</FilesMatch>
# END LBCWpFastestCache
# BEGIN GzipWpFastestCache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>
# END GzipWpFastestCache
# BEGIN WpFastestCache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-login.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Wap-Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond /homez.716/mywebsite/www/en/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html" [L]
</IfModule>
# END WpFastestCache
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php .php3 .php4 .htm .html
AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php .php3 .php4 .htm .html
# BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress
```

When I create a file named `phptest.php`

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

Then I check with browser it output

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

The php script not being executed. what is the problem and how to solve this?

Comment: did you add the htaccess or was it there when you opened the account?

Comment: I am not sure, But I see it existed already.

Comment: Remark! it is the shared hosting

Comment: if Deleted or just Rename the .htaccess file , the php code will can be generate the output.

Comment: suggest you merely rename it, or at least make a backup. you'll probably need it for wordpress to work properly

Comment: probably just the `AddType` and `AddHandler` lines at fault

Comment: Remove the `AddType x-mapp-php5 …` and `AddHandler x-mapp-php5 …` lines at the end. Your hoster is probably running a different setup than the one those lines were intended for.

Comment: Side note, why do people still use shared hosting in 2015? VPS's/Cloud are like `$10` a month and you have full control of your server. Who needs the headache of limitations?

Comment: Thanks CBroe, and All ,  It works.